# How do I display an error dialog from content editor command?

Tags: content-editor, sheer-ui, commands

How do I show an error style dialog (i.e. with red error logo and the expand text) from a content editor command?

I've tried to use `SheerResponse.ShowError()`. The content editor greys out like it does for regular modals / dialogs, but no error message appears. I'm using Sitecore 8.0 update 3. My code is below:

```cs
public class MyCommand: Command
{
    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection();
        if (context.Items.Length == 1)
        {
            Item item = context.Items[0];
            if (item != null
                && item.TemplateID.ToString() == Templates.RedirectSettings.TemplateId)
            {
                nameValueCollection["id"] = item.ID.ToString();
                Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DoStuff", nameValueCollection);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void DoStuff(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        var itemId = args.Parameters["id"];
        if (!args.IsPostBack)
        {
            SheerResponse.Confirm("Do stuff now?");
            args.WaitForPostBack();
        }
        else if (args.Result == "yes")
        {
            var everythingOk = //do some stuff and check if successfull..
            if (everythingOk)
            {
                SheerResponse.Alert("Everything worked ok", true, "It's ok");
            }
            else
            {
                //something went wrong
                SheerResponse.ShowError("My short description", "Detailed description...");
                args.WaitForPostBack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

As far as I remember, Sitecore 8 support for Sheer has been dropped in favour of SPEAK.

[Here](http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-ribbon-button-transfiguration/) you can find more information on how to convert a button from Sheer to SPEAK.

In essence you have to use JavaScript for that and create a function according to the template below:

```js
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
    Sitecore.Commands.YourCommandName = {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            return true; // check if the command can execute
        },
        execute: function (context) {
            var id = context.currentContext.itemId;
            var lang = context.currentContext.language;
            var ver = context.currentContext.version;

            // here comes your code

            alert("Error!"); // use javascript here to show info or ask for confirmaiton
        }
    };
});
```

Then connect it to the presentation of the button. Refer to [this link](http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-ribbon-button-transfiguration/) for the detailed information.

More info about Speak can be found [here](https://mhwelander.net/2014/06/27/speak-for-newbies-part-1-creating-a-new-application/).

Comment: So does this mean that to invoke C# code I would need a controller returning a JSON result for success/failure?

Comment: Sitecore provides means to execute code by RequestProcessors. You can see how it's done in the linked article (first link from the answer)

Comment: Just a small correction, Sheer has not been dropped. It's still there and can be used as needed, depending on which part of the application you're connecting into.

Answer (score 5):

I have decompile the Sitecore Code and below is an example how the popup appeared:

This screenshot is from the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Upload` namespace

[image]

So, you can make use of the `Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Specify at least one file to upload.");`

The code can take up to 3 parameters. You can specify the response and the header. For the response, you can pass 1 or blank. The 1 represent True

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert("Your error message");
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was trying to create yes/no/cancel dialog box on client page. One of my observation was this, When I added the command link on Sitecore control panel, it was not opening the dialog box at all. But added the command link as a button in the ribbon bar worked for me. 
I shared the details on this article “How to create and use Sitecore command” by Alok Bhatt https://link.medium.com/qoqctiM4Q5