# It does not appear that i can use SheerResponse.Confirm in Sitecore 8. What can I use?

Tags: sheer-ui

I have been trying to display a message inside a StandardValidator but when I use SheerResponse.Confirm i receive a null object exception in Sitecore 8. What should I use instead?

```cs
private ValidatorResult IsValid(Item item)
{
  //ClientPage in null
  Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Alert(String.Format(Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text(DictionaryKeys.EventCardCollectionNotSavedErrorMessage)));

  //throws null object exception
  SheerResponse.Confirm

  return ValidatorResult.Valid;
}
```

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Charlie, can you provide a bit more info into how you're trying to display the message?  Potentially, if you can, sanitize and provide us a code snippet showing us some context around SheerResponse?

Comment: Hi, basically when i use the code snippet above i receive a null object exception in Sitecore 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at my answer to this question: [How do I display an error dialog from content editor command?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/243/display-error-dialog-from-content-editor-command/248#248)

> As far as I remember in Sitecore 8 support for Sheer has been droped
>   in favour of Speak.

Comment: But i am trying to display a popup in a implementation of StandardValidator?.  Does this mean i cannot do it in c# anymore?